# Generate entity framework entities with XML data

Tags: xml, entity-framework, dto

I have needed in my system to read data from an XML file and populate DTOs with that data. These data are to be manipulated using Entity Framework.

Is there any already existing mechanism or an extension of entity framework or any better approach you can suggest to achieve the same.

The structure of the XML file is not an issue. It can be generated in any required structure.

Comment: can you try https://xef.codeplex.com/

Comment: For a pure MS answer: I usually use [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). You may also look at [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).